# Custom segue, scaling out the source view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Attempting to write a custom segue where the source view is scaled out, while changing the alpha of the destination to fade the destination in.  The destination is a MKMapView, so I want it updating as the fade occurs.
With what I've tried I end up with the source and designation scaling out simultaneously, and I can't get just the source view to scale out.

```
    class Map_Segue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform()
    {
        var sourceViewController      : UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        var destinationViewController : UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController           
        destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0            sourceViewController.addChildViewController(destinationViewController)            sourceViewController.view.addSubview(destinationViewController.view)            
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0,delay:1.0,options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, // delay of 1 second for aesthetics
            animations:
            {
                sourceViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sourceViewController.view.transform, 100.0, 100.0);
                destinationViewController.view.alpha = 1;
            },
            completion:
            {  (finished:Bool)->Void in
                destinationViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(sourceViewController);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried `autoresizesSubviews=false`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried setting the destination transform in the animation to be 1/100 (and set the options to `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear` which has the final result correct, but the transition effect is wrong (map in the background scaled up then down again)
I'm sure this should be easy, and I'm missing a trick as I'm new to this.
Anyone got any ideas?

**Update:**

I've found that (somewhat obviously) I should use `sourceViewController.view.superview?.insertSubview( destinationViewController.view, atIndex:0)` to insert it alongside the original source view, rather than as a child of it, that way, obviously, the transform is independent, not with respect to the views parent (which it will be as a subview).  The problem then is swapping to the new view.  Using the method I had, viewWillAppear and similar are not called, and the changing over the views does not work. If I call presentViewController, then we get a glitch when viewWillAppear is called.

**Solution so far**

Forget using custom segues.  Followed the suggestion and placed a UIImageView on top of the map view, and had a beautiful animating fade in about 5 minutes of coding.

Comment: I think an image would clarify what you are trying to accomplish. One thing I see here: You add the destinationView as a child to the sourceView and then you perform the animation on the sourceView, which of course affects the destinationView, too...?

Comment: yes, that's the problem - how do I prevent the source view transform from affecting the destination?  Is there a different way to do this, whilst having both views active?  Will see if I can create a visual of what I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: What about a viewController wich holds 2 containerViews, the sourceViewController and the destinationViewController, and perform the animations on these two viewControllers? Just a thought...

Comment: Thats a thought - will try that.  Was hoping to use seques so I could mix and match a bit.  An example of the look is similar to the twitter bird logo when you start the twitter app - is zooms out and reveals what is behind (though rather than using a cutout and alpha, I'm after a fade).

Comment: I finally went for your suggestion of two views - a UIImageView on top of the MKMapView, and faded out the animating UIImageView to give the desired effect.  A lot easier than custom segues.  Thanks for the suggetion

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused with parent and child view controllers etc. It is sufficient to *temporarily* add the second view controller's view to the first one, perform the transitions and then clean up.

I tested the following in a simple sample project. Note that I am adding the second view controller's view to the window rather than the first view controller's view because otherwise it would also get scaled up.

```
override func perform() {
    let first = self.sourceViewController as ViewController
    let second = self.destinationViewController as ViewController

    second.view.alpha = 0
    first.view.window!.addSubview(second.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, 
     options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        first.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(100.0, 100.0)
        second.view.alpha = 1.0
     })
     { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        second.view.removeFromSuperview()
        first.presentViewController(second, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mundi, yes, I may be slightly confused over them, and I am only trying to add temporarily.  I tried your method, but it appears not to update the subview (second.view) even though added.  The addChildViewController/didMoveToParentViewController is an attempt to remove the flicker created by presentViewController which I believe is due to the view being initialised a 2nd time (once for the addSubView, once for the presentViewController)